# How to copy list item from parent site to subsite?

Tags: list, wss-3.0

I have a list in the parent site and I want to copy the items to its subsite.

Is it possible? 
Is it possible to only copy some items that are fulfill some criteria?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes it is possible but when do you need them to copy? I mean at what point in time? OOB I don't think its available but can be done by simple coding, either a Timer Job or Visual Web Part if you want to handle it manually on a button click or something!

Comment: How do you want copy the item: with a web part or a scripts or ...

Comment: If the Publishing Feature is on. You can use Manage Content Source from Site Action. Select the items to be moved, use the Move/Copy Options and choose the site where you want to move ur content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you could export the list via powershell and import it in the subsite. This link should answer your question: [Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jorman/copying-lists-with-powershell-in-sharepoint-2010)

I would first export and import all items. Afterwards you can create a view based on your criteria and delete not needed items.